# Background-color behind a border-radius

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, is it possible to set a background-color behind the border-radius?

I want to achieve this effect:
[image]

I use this HTML:

```
<div class="content-header" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="html">TITLE</span>
</div>
<div class="content-txt-v2" tabindex="-1">
  <p>
  Content
  </p>        
</div>
```

and I use this CSS:

```
.content-header {
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: #4C741B;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;    
    padding: 0px 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#fff;
}
.content-txt-v2 {
    clear: both;
    width: 669px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
      border: 2px solid #E9EAE3;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I added the above code in a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/85c8ss94/)

I tried to set the background-color of my content-txt-v2 div but with no succes. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Is it possible with only two div's? or should I add more objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this? it gives you desired output without much headache!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content-header {
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #4C741B;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  /* z-index same as red bar*/
  position: relative;
}
.content-header:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  background: #4C741B;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
  /* z-index less than red bar*/
}
.content-txt-v2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 669px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 2px solid #E9EAE3;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  /* for giving z-index */
  z-index: 10;
  /* z-index equal to title block */
}
```

```html
<div class="content-header" tabindex="-1">
  <span class="html">TITLE</span>
</div>
<div class="content-txt-v2" tabindex="-1">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is also a very good solution. In the end I used your solution in order to avoid using negative margins. Thank you!

Comment: yeah.. that was the advantage. I was going to share both the solutions, one this one and other same as shared by @Jonas, but i dropped it due to that negative margin and height/width issues

Answer (score 3):

That is pretty hard to do, but you can fake it: https://jsfiddle.net/85c8ss94/1/

```
.content-header {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: #4C741B;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;    
    padding: 0px 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
}
.content-txt-v2 {
    clear: both;
    width: 669px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid #E9EAE3;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
```